# Get array of strings from plain string ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have a string pattern like below,

```
 => "text1 http://www.domain.com/experiment_B_setup_diagram_image.png\n\nExperiments text2 http://www.domain.com/experiment_C_setup_diagram_image.png \nexperiment text3 http://www.domain.com/experiment_A_plotted_cha
rt.png"
```

I want to have to separate url and then string one by one like, the output should be,

```
> ["text1",
> "http://www.domain.com/experiment_B_setup_diagram_image.png",
> "\n\nExperiments", "text2",
> "http://www.domain.com/experiment_C_setup_diagram_image.png",
> "\nexperiment", "text3",........]
```

like separate url and its preceeding or succeeding strings as an array...Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: no idea...im not good in RE

Comment: You should try something, StackOverflow it is not a _write-code-for-me_ service.

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" will help you also.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
.split(/\s|\n+/)
```

For example:

```
text="text1 http://www.domain.com/experiment_B_setup_diagram_image.png\n\nExperiments text2 http://www.domain.com/experiment_C_setup_diagram_image.png \nexperiment text3 http://www.domain.com/experiment_A_plotted_chart.png"
text.split(/\s|\n/)
```

Which returns:

```
["text1", "http://www.domain.com/experiment_B_setup_diagram_image.png", "", "Experiments", "text2", "http://www.domain.com/experiment_C_setup_diagram_image.png", "", "experiment", "text3", "http://www.domain.com/experiment_A_plotted_chart.png"]
```

Comment: Using `\s+` is sufficient as it already includes `\n` in its char set. Look at its definition in http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes

Comment: Also, `\s|\n+` is probably not doing what you think it is. See https://www.regex101.com/r/wF8xU6/1 for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're OK with dropping the line feeds (\n), you can convert them to a space first and then simply split on spaces:

```
x = "text1 http://www.domain.com/experiment_B_setup_diagram_image.png\n\nExperiments text2 http://www.domain.com/experiment_C_setup_diagram_image.png \nexperiment text3 http://www.domain.com/experiment_A_plotted_chart.png"
x.tr("\n", " ").split(" ")
```

Comment: It's a long way around. Instead use a regex with `split` to handle both spaces and newlines.

Comment: OP mentioned they weren't good with regex so this was presented as an alternative. The regex is minor of course,  but for the problem isn't entirely necessary.